# Finding text in Selenium webdriver XPATH using contains

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on 30 Days of Python - Day 16 - Scrape & Automate behind Password Protected Apps with Selenium & Python.

However, I found that using XPATH to find the button 'Follow' in Instagram is not working.

```
def click_to_follow(browser):
   my_follow_btn_xpath = '//*[contains(text()='follow')]'
    follow_btn_els = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, my_follow_btn_xpath)
    for btn in follow_btn_els:
        try:
            btn.click()
        except:
            pass


new_user = 'ted'
new_user_url = f'http://www.instagram.com/{new_user}/'
browser.get(new_user_url)

click_to_follow(browser)
```

The above is the code, but it shows that I had an invalid syntax.

```
 my_follow_btn_xpath = '//*[contains(text()='follow')]'
                                                ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could any one help with this? I have search for similar posts but I still can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use single quotes inside your xpath.

Change this:

```
my_follow_btn_xpath = '//*[contains(text()='follow')]'
```

to this:

```
my_follow_btn_xpath = '//*[contains(text()="follow")]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:
Note: You took `Follow` as `follow`. The text is `Follow`, not `follow`
[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuFB7.png)

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Follow']"))).click()
```

This would be the specific element that you want:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//h1//parent::div//div[text()='Follow']"))).click()
```